# Is there a way to alphabetically sort query parameters in retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I want the url parameters to be sorted in alphabetical order in retrofit. Following two urls are cached separately. Is there a way to sort this alphabetically in retrofit.

/getData?tag1=a&tag2=b and  /getData?tag2=b&tag1=a

```
 @GET("getData")
 suspend fun getData(
            @Query("tag1") tag1: Int,
            @Query("tag2") tag2: Int
)
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: We currently have a cache called varnish which treats it two different urls

Comment: Making the clients solve a backend problem seems like a repetitive solution, now every client will have to diplicate the solution, at leat 3; android, IOS, web.

Comment: It looks like there are ways to have Varnish sort the query parameters: https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/urlplus/

Comment: @CommonsWare How to do this in retrofit.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible. Fix your Varnish configuration.